# Using grid2poly with raster

Tags: r, kml, raster, r-raster

I am trying to take data from a raster and push it to KML format so that I get a series of gridded polygons.

Looking at samples on the web it would appear that the way to go is to using `grid2poly` with `plotKML`.  Unfortunately I have hit an error that I can seem to unblock.

```
library(dismo)
require(plotKML)

library(rgdal)

tmin <- getData("worldclim", var = "tmin", res = 10)  # this will download 
# global data on minimum temperature at 10' resolution

tmin1 <- raster(paste(getwd(), "/wc10/tmin1.bil", sep = ""))  # Tmin for     January

newext <- c(-1, 1, 40, 43.5)
tmin1.c <- crop(tmin1, newext)
plot(tmin1.c)

tmin1.c  # look at the info
head(tmin1.c,5)

tminvals <- rasterToPoints(tmin1.c)

tminvals # look at the info
head(tminvals,5)
str(tminvals)

###########################
#Everything works down to here
###########################

library(sp)
coordinates(tminvals) <- ~x+y
gridded(tminvals) <- TRUE

proj4string(tminvals) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
data(SAGA_pal)

dem_poly <- grid2poly(tminvals, "tmin1", method = "sp")

## visualize the data in Google Earth:
kml(dem_poly, colour_scale = SAGA_pal[[1]], colour = tmin1, kmz = TRUE)
```

I get an error  for all the lines from `coordinates(tminvals) <- ~x+y` which looks like this:

> From Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates<-’ for signature ‘"matrix"’

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  When I look at the dataset `tminvals`  It looks much the same in content as the original example data `eberg_grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why polygons and not a raster KML?

```
library(raster)
tmin <- getData("worldclim", var = "tmin", res = 10) 
tmin1 <- tmin[[1]]
newext <- c(-1, 1, 40, 43.5)
tmin1.c <- crop(tmin1, newext)

KML(tmin.c, 'test.kml')
```

If you need polygons:

```
p <- rasterToPolygons(tmin.c)
```

and now you can use KML (or kml) again

Now to explain the error message you are getting. The coordinates function expects a data.frame, you are giving it a matrix. It will probably go away if you do this:

```
tminvals <- data.frame(tminvals)
coordinates(tminvals) <- ~x+y
```

Comment: You suggestions worked - many thanks.  I want to use polygons to introduce some exagguration in the vertical scale.  The problem is that even when I have _plotKML(tminvals, altitude=5000+tmin1*100, tessellate= TRUE, extrude= TRUE)_ in the kml file itself the <altitudeMode> is set to 'clampedtoground'.  I can use a text editor to chnage this to absolute but I really want to do it all from R .

Comment: I just discovered the alpha, altitude and altitudeMode parameters!